# Optimizing or replace while loop join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, optimization, while-loop

My stored procedure has two while loops and it takes too much time to execute for 10000 records. Is there any way too reduce the complexity of the code. the structure of procedure are below given

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcAllotApp]
    @DocumentElement XML,
    @IPA varchar(20), 
    @UserID varchar(5),
    @OutStatus varchar(10) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ApplicationDetails)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AppCount int
        DECLARE @id int

        SET @AppCount = (SELECT COUNT(Application_id) FROM #ApplicationDetails)
        SET @id = 1

        -- Loop start for selecting Application id (Master loop)
        WHILE (@AppCount > 0)
        BEGIN
            -- All variable declaration
            DECLARE @App varchar(20)
            DECLARE @Count int
            DECLARE @pref int
            DECLARE @U_Code varchar(12)
            DECLARE @MOI varchar(7)
            DECLARE @RemSeat int
            DECLARE @AllotedApp int
            DECLARE @CCode varchar(5)
                
            -- set values
            SET @App = (SELECT Application_id FROM #ApplicationDetails WHERE id = @id)
            SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT U_Code) FROM S_Preference WHERE App = @App)
            SET @pref = 1

            WHILE (@count > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET commands
                    -- Insert, update in some tables
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: See if you can directly use the "merge statement" here.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Actually there is insertion  happened in multiple table also there is also if-else clause which I erases here from the  above code due to security point. @kevin Shah

Comment: that is ok @KAbhishek so sql merge statement will not be used here right? Also this process will be one time or ongoing process that you need to do frequently?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please explain why you are looping instead of just updating all at once.

Comment: Yeah, merge is not applicable here. this is a ongoing process and definitely be run frequently by the user @kevin shah

Comment: Okay, I'll try to add sample structure so that you get better clarity @philipxy

Comment: First - if you need to loop just use a cursor. Your looping structure is no more efficient and often less efficient. Next, don't loop - your RBAR thinking that drives you to this method is your primary problem. Your comments also suggest that your schema is a factor and changing it might be a better long-term solution. But without the detail that you intentionally omitted, it is impossible to make useful suggests. You can try to optimize the statements inside the loop and your existing tables, but a set-based approach would likely be better.